# Python string-bytes to bytes

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have *string* data that look like bytes reprs of JSON in Python

```
>>> data = """b'{"a": 1, "b": 2}\n'"""
```

So on the inside of that, we have valid JSON that looks like it's been byte-encoded. I want to *decode* the bytes and `loads` the JSON on the inside, but since its a string I cannot.

```
>>> data.decode() # nope
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Encoding the string doesn't seem to help either:

```
>>> data.encode() # wrong
b'b\'{"a": 1, "b": 2}\n\''
```

There are oodles of string-to-bytes questions on stackoverflow, but for the life of me I cannot find anything about this particular issue. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Things that I do not want to do and/or will not work:

1. `eval` the data into a bytes object
2. strip the `b` and `\n` (inside of my JSON there's all sorts of other escaped data).

This is the only working solution I have found, and there is a *lot* not to like about it:

```
from ast import literal_eval

data = """b'{"a": 1, "b": 2}\n'"""
print(literal_eval(data[:-2] + data[-1:]).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: "I have string data that look like bytes reprs of JSON in Python" - that sounds like a bug you should fix on the producing end.

Comment: I wish i could solve it on that end! These are actually airflow logs vis structlog that i must analyze

Comment: "These are actually airflow logs vis structlog that i must analyze" - in the future, you can probably configure structlog to give you something more useful. Avoiding textual log parsing is supposed to be one of the primary goals of structlog.

Comment: Anyway, `ast.literal_eval`. There's probably a good dupe target somewhere around here.

Comment: Yes, the ast idea looks better. If you can find a partial eval for this...

Comment: ast _will_ work but the data need to be sanitized first (note that newline breaks everything)

Comment: The weird slicing you had to do in your `literal_eval` attempt is almost certainly due to a bug you introduced while attempting to write a string literal for `data` - you've got an actual newline in the middle of your bytes literal, which is invalid syntax for a bytes literal. You probably meant for that to be an actual backslash and n - that, or the newline was supposed to be outside the bytes literal.

Comment: `data = r"""b'{"a": 1, "b": 2}\n'"""` is likely more representative of the actual kinds of values you're working with. If it's *not*, then that's going to be an issue.

Comment: If the text in your log file looks like `b'{"a": 1, "b": 2}\n'`, then you can `ast.literal_eval` that with no issue. If the text in your log file looks like `b'{"a": 1, "b": 2}` and then `'` on the next line, then your string literal accurately represents that, and you're going to have issues.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you didn't want to strip the `b` inside the string due to other escaped data, but can't we assume that whatever generated this only output ascii (hence the `b`), and we can re-encode that. So I was thinking you can use a simple regexp (https://regex101.com/r/M0ratk/1) which you then encode as bytes.

```
import json
import re

match = re.match(r"\Ab'(.*)'\Z", data, re.DOTALL)
data = json.loads(bytes(match[1], 'ascii'))
```

Will this work? I am not sure how it compares to the `literal_eval` solution.

Comment: Never in my wildest dreams did i picture a regex solution wow wow

Comment: What can I say, when you spend a good portion of every work day writing regex, everything starts looking like a regex problem 

Comment: @NolanConaway and now you have two problems.  (It's a famous quote, look it up)