# convert python string of byte data to bytes

Tags: python, encoding, byte, binary-data

I have a Python string of bytes data. An example string looks like this:

```
string = "b'\xabVJ-K\xcd+Q\xb2R*.M*N.\xcaLJU\xd2QJ\xceH\xcc\xcbK\xcd\x01\x89\x16\xe4\x97\xe8\x97d&g\xa7\x16Y\x85\x06\xbb8\xeb\x02\t\xa5Z\x00'"
```

It is a string, it not not `bytes`. I wish to convert it to bytes. Normal approaches (like `encode`) yield this:

```
b'\\xabVJ-K\\xcd+Q\\xb2R*.M*N.\\xcaLJU\\xd2QJ\\xceH\\xcc\\xcbK\\xcd\\x01\\x89\\x16\\xe4\\x97\\xe8\\x97d&g\\xa7\\x16Y\\x85\\x06\\xbb8\\xeb\\x02\\t\\xa5Z\\x00'
```

which leads to issues (note the addition of all the extra slashes).

I've looked through 10+ potential answers to this question on SO and only one of them works, and its a solution I'd prefer not to use, for obvious reasons:

```
this_works = eval(string)
```

Is there any way to get this to work without eval? Other potential solutions I've tried, that failed:

[Option 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65329655/python-string-bytes-to-bytes)
[Option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60340519/convert-stringed-bytes-back-into-bytes)
[Option 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754731/python-convert-strings-of-bytes-to-byte-array)

Comment: The third option should work, once you remove the extraneous 'b' and quotes.  `s[2:-1].encode('latin')`

Comment: I still get the same error I mentioned above, addition of extra backslashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have python-like string representation in variable `s`:

```
s = r"b'\xabVJ-K\xcd+Q\xb2R*.M*N.\xcaLJU\xd2QJ\xceH\xcc\xcbK\xcd\x01\x89\x16\xe4\x97\xe8\x97d&g\xa7\x16Y\x85\x06\xbb8\xeb\x02\t\xa5Z\x00'"
```

Yes, if you eval this then you got real python `bytes` object.
But you can try parse it with `ast` module:

```py
import ast
s = r"b'\xabVJ-K\xcd+Q\xb2R*.M*N.\xcaLJU\xd2QJ\xceH\xcc\xcbK\xcd\x01\x89\x16\xe4\x97\xe8\x97d&g\xa7\x16Y\x85\x06\xbb8\xeb\x02\t\xa5Z\x00'"
tree = ast.parse(s)
value = tree.body[0].value.value
print(type(value), value)
```

This will output your `bytes` object:

```sh
<class 'bytes'> b'\xabVJ-K\xcd+Q\xb2R*.M*N.\xcaLJU\xd2QJ\xceH\xcc\xcbK\xcd\x01\x89\x16\xe4\x97\xe8\x97d&g\xa7\x16Y\x85\x06\xbb8\xeb\x02\t\xa5Z\x00'
```

Comment: yeah, I dont want to use eval or the like, I'm reading this data from a file, its a mixed format file (so has normal text with binary/bytes data). Just evaluating like that seems like an issue

Comment: actually, I stand corrected - it looks like ast parse will not eval anything, let me give this a try

Comment: It does work. I wish there were a better way, but thats ok. I wonder if there is a way to do it with struct. I tried a few things, but couldnt get any of them to work.

Comment: I suppose that there is no simple solution because representation is _very_ python-specific (non-ascii bytes in `\x00` format and special wrapping `b'...'`). Python `struct` just works with raw bytes objects.